# Upgraded C# MVC project EF 4.7.2 to .net Core 8.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, upgrade

Upgraded C# MVC project EF 4.7.2 to .net Core 8.0, on build my solution, I got the below error.

> 'OperationContext' does not contain a definition for 'ServiceSecurityContext' and no accessible extension method 'ServiceSecurityContext' accepting a first argument of type 'OperationContext' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

```cs
using System.Security.Principal;
using System.ServiceModel;

if (OperationContext.Current != null)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(OperationContext.Current.ServiceSecurityContext.WindowsIdentity.Name))
    {
        return OperationContext.Current.ServiceSecurityContext.WindowsIdentity.Name;
    }

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(OperationContext.Current.ServiceSecurityContext.PrimaryIdentity.Name))
    {
        return OperationContext.Current.ServiceSecurityContext.PrimaryIdentity.Name;
    }
}
```

I tried to install `System.ServiceModel.Primitive` and it didn't work.

Comment: Are you using `upgrade assistance tool`, if not, it is highly recommended way to make the transition from .NET Framework to .NET https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/platform/upgrade-assistant

Comment: I think the `OperationContext` is removed, (but not sure). there was a trend in ASP.NET to remove all the statics, so this could have been removed also, I think you need to inject `HttpContext` and from that, we can reach the current user Name

Comment: By the way, I think we also need more information, Are this project ASP.NET, WCF, or normal .NET Framework, can you provide more context to the above code by determining if this code is inside Controller or not?

Comment: Hi @Hakan, I used upgrade assistance tool. I upgraded  .sln which has projects of ASP.NET MVC and WCF from EF 4.7.2 to .net core 8. The WCF project failed with the 'OperationContext'  as stated above.

Comment: if you have WCF then you need some more effort as the migrating of WCF is not straightforward, are you aware of the project https://github.com/CoreWCF/CoreWCF, I think you should consult the documentation of the project for your specific problem